# VueJS: Trying to compile two CSS files in /dist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I just began using Vue and I'm hitting a wall while trying to compile SCSS into separate files. I understand that any SCSS that I'm writing within components will be compiled into a single file (`/dist/css/app[hash].css`), but I would like separate files which aren't imported into any component for external use.

I have several SCSS files (`frames.scss`, `lists.scss`, and `tables.scss` ) that I would like to be compiled, minified, and prefixed into their own CSS files alongside the aforementioned CSS file.

I would like the build structure to look something like this (with the external CSS file existing alongside the app CSS file):

```
dist/
  css/
    app[hash].css
    frames.css
    lists.css
    tables.css
```

I have very little experience with Webpack, so my `vue.config.js` file is currently empty and my `postcss.config.js` file is below:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    autoprefixer: {}
  }
}
```

I've searched all over StackOverflow for a solution to no avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For webpack 4, I think you want to look at [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin).

its a webpack plugin that, by, default, creates different files per input. You can use this with scss as you would expect. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180597/6646536 might be a good example.

There is a similar tool i've used for webpack 3 here:
 https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your response! I've tried endless permutations of setting up my webpack.config.js file, but unfortunately the files will not compile. The SCSS files that I mentioned above are not required in any JS files (but have been set as the entry), which I suspect is the issue.

Comment: That is correct, for webpack to know about the files and process them, they have to be required or imported in some way. If you are into the idea, you can make a main scss file and [import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import), or if your application has an entry point, `require` them there